# How to submit HTML multiple forms generated by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On ajax success i have list of generated forms:

```
...
            success: function (data) {
            $el.append('<form method="POST" class="submit_form">Name: '+data[i].namen+' 
        Id: '+data[i].id+'<br>   SomethignElse: <label id="red">'+data[i].se+'</label><br> SomethingElse2: '+data[i].se2+'
            <input type="text" name="id" value="'+data[i].id+'" id="id_test" /> 
    <input type="button" class="submit_button1"  value="Add"/></form><br>');
    i = ++ i;
            }
...
```

Also i have a click functionto submit this forms/form:

```
 $(".submit_button1").click(function(){
//do something
});
```

but nothing happens on click. Is it possible to submit in this way?

Comment: Only one form can be submitted at a time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try `.on('click'` event listner.

```
$(document).on('click','.submit_button1',function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Thank You working fine for me